# insert a closing tag </ul> inside an if within foreach loop in a partial view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

when you see the code it'll be much clearer -

```
@{
    <ul>
        @foreach (SDNCMS.Models.CountryModel curCountry in Model)
        {
            <li><a href="#" id="@curCountry.Name">@curCountry.Name</a></li>
                if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)
                {
                    </ul>
                    <ul> 
                }
            }
    </ul>
}
```

i'm getting this error :

The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

I've tried `Html.Raw`()

how can i get it to work ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `@:` operator to output plain text to the page:

```
@{
    <ul>
        @foreach (SDNCMS.Models.CountryModel curCountry in Model)
        {
            <li><a href="#" id="@curCountry.Name">@curCountry.Name</a></li>
                if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)
                {
                    @:</ul><ul> 
                }
            }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `@foreach` to this: `@{foreach` and close this block with `}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)` to `@if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you change the

```
</ul>
<ul>
```

part to be :

```
@Html.Raw("</ul><ul>")
```

then it will output to the page. You also might need to add an @ before the inner if to indicate begining of new code block e.g.

```
@if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this :

```
<ul>
    @foreach (SDNCMS.Models.CountryModel curCountry in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#" id="@curCountry.Name">@curCountry.Name</a></li>
        if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("</ul><ul>") 
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight rearrangement of your code:

```
<ul> 
@{
    foreach (SDNCMS.Models.CountryModel curCountry in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#" id="@curCountry.Name">@curCountry.Name</a></li>
        @if (curCountry.ID % 9 == 0)
        {
            </ul>
            <ul> 
        }
    }
} 
</ul>
```